# Need to assertValue of text input field based on data coming from a table td inner HTML (using storeText to store variable) in Selenium IDE script

Tags: selenium

In Selenium IDE, I need to call the command `assertValue` of an input field on data coming from a table `<td>` (which only allows `storeText`, not `storeValue`) from a different page.

Right now the data is being stored correctly, but I think the `assertValue` command requires a value variable, not a text variable. I found out from past situations that these are different things to the IDE.

**I tried the following, but it didn't work:**

Store text variable from table `<td>` tag:

```
Command: storeText
Target: //table[@id='AddressList_List_ListGrid']/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]
Value: var_source_client_billing_address_city
```

Store text variable into value variable:

```
Command: storeValue
Target: ${var_source_client_billing_address_city)
Value: var_source_client_billing_address_city_value
```

**Crashes on command above, so I can't even use the value variable to assert the value**

Assert value variable in text input field:

```
Command: assertValue
Target: id=AddressEditor_TxtCity
Value: ${var_source_client_billing_address_city_value}
```

**This also did not work:**

Store text variable from table `<td>` tag:

```
Command: storeText
Target: //table[@id='AddressList_List_ListGrid']/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]
Value: var_source_client_billing_address_city
```

Assert value variable in text input field:

```
Command: assertValue
Target: id=AddressEditor_TxtCity
Value: ${var_source_client_billing_address_city}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the first set to work, but for comparing the text variable (created with `storeText`) and the value variable (created with `storeValue`), I just used `assertExpression`.

**Store text variable from table td tag inner HTML**

```
Command: storeText
Target: //table[@id='AddressList_List_ListGrid']/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]
Value: var_source_client_billing_address_city
```

**Store text variable into value variable**

```
Command: storeValue
Target: ${var_source_client_billing_address_city)
Value: var_source_client_billing_address_city_value
```

**Assert value variable in text input field to text value from td inner HTML**

```
Command: assertExpression
Target: ${var_source_client_billing_address_city}
Value: ${var_source_client_billing_address_city_value}
```